# Make custom title view from defaults on Android

Tags: android

How do I use androids default window title style to make my own similar `TextView`?

I have done a lot of guessing and made a TextView that has everything that
the default title bar has, except for the text shadow (and some padding/margins etc. I think).

Here's essentially what I've tried:

MainUI.xml

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
}
```

title_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:id="@+id/myTitle"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle"
  android:background="@android:drawable/title_bar"
  android:text="This is my new title" />
```

**Edit:**

I found some interesting related articles at [makemachine](http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/custom-android-window-title/) and [anddev](http://www.anddev.org/my_own_titlebar_backbutton_like_on_the_iphone-t4591.html).

Although I don't like it, I copied some attributes from the implementation [style.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=d7b654e49809cb97a35682754b1394af5c8bc88b;hb=HEAD).

Is there any way to avoid copying the attributes in this static way?

The following rendered almost perfect, the difference is in fact that the original did "cut" the first 2-3 pixels of the title shadow, while my `TextView` doesn't.

```
<TextView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:id="@+id/myTitle"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:shadowColor="#BB000000"
  android:shadowRadius="2.75"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle"
  android:background="@android:drawable/title_bar"
  android:text="This is my new title" />
```

It's also important to override the default android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle with a transparent color, because the default includes some padding etc. that you don't want to be wrapping your custom title bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Remember to enable the theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Are you willing to copy the default titlebar made by Android?

Comment: Yes, as long as I can modify it. I want the title bar to also function as a progress bar :-)

Comment: dont know if this will help or not, but [RomManager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&hl=en) does that when you go to download roms, the title bar fills up with grey from left to right as it is loading. if you run it while running Hierarchy viewer you can see they have the progress bar and progress circle thing.

Answer (score 0):

try this it worked for me:

put the rest of the code in place..

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.main_header);
     TextView  home = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home);
       if ( home != null ) {
            /*  your code here */
           home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // the action that u want to perform
                Menu.this.finish();
                Intent i= new Intent(Main.this,Destination.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        }
```

**create a main_header layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Main Menu"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="10pt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here when we execute the code it will show a custom title bar where there are two text's in it and when we click on that it will go the next class ( to your destination  class). we can also change the color , size font etc.. and also add buttons etc to the custom title bar.